# How to create an Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm new to satellite image processing and google earth engine. I'm trying to display the bands of an Image Collection, but when I print them on console, the band list is empty. Am I doing it right? If not, how do we make an Image Collection on google earth engine? A step by step elaboration would be really helpful.

Also, I did not take 'mean()' because I want the bands to map over the entire image collection, rather than reducing it to an image

```
  function maskClouds(image) {
  
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    var cloudShadowBitMask = 1<<3;
    var cloudsBitMask = 1<<5;  
    
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
    
     // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
    
      // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
  
  var addNDVI = function (image){
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
  };

  var addEVI = function (image){
    var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - Red) / (NIR + 6 * Red - 7.5 * Blue + 1))',{    // C1=6, C2=7.5, L=1
    'NIR': image.select('B5'),
    'Red': image.select('B4'),
    'Blue': image.select('B2'),
    }).rename('EVI');
  evi = evi.toFloat();
  return image.addBands(evi);
  };
  var addNDWI = function (image){ 
    var ndwi = image.expression(
    'NDWI = (Green – NIR) / (Green + NIR)',{
      'Green': image.select('B3'),
      'NIR': image.select('B5')
    });
  ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B3']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndwi);
  };
  
 var addMSAVI = function (image){
   var msavi = image.expression(
   '(2 * nir + 1 - ( (2 * nir + 1)**2 - 8 * (nir -red) )**(1/2) ) / 2',{
     'nir': image.select('B5'),
     'red': image.select('B4')
   });
  msavi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('MSAVI');
  return image.addBands(msavi);
 };



var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-01-15')
.map(maskClouds)
.map(addNDVI)
.map(addEVI)
.map(addNDWI)
.map(addMSAVI);

print(l8);
```

The output on console having an empty band list:

```
ImageCollection LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA (4800 elements)
type: ImageCollection
id: LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA
version: 1658276094802348
bands: []
features: List (4800 elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. First of all, you are searching in the wrong place. You should watch in band list of whatever feature of 4800 elements of the ImageCollection; as it can be observed as follows. Each one has 21 bands. The band list is not empty as you supossed.

```
ImageCollection LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA (4800 elements)
type: ImageCollection
id: LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA
version: 1658276094802348
bands: []
features: List (4800 elements)
0: Image LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA/LC08_001049_20210103 (21 bands)
type: Image
id: LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA/LC08_001049_20210103
version: 1658276094802348
bands: List (21 elements)
0: "B1", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
1: "B2", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
2: "B3", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
3: "B4", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
4: "B5", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
5: "B6", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
6: "B7", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
7: "B8", float, EPSG:32620, 15101x15421 px
8: "B9", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
9: "B10", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
10: "B11", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
11: "QA_PIXEL", unsigned int16, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
12: "QA_RADSAT", unsigned int16, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
13: "SAA", signed int16, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
14: "SZA", signed int16, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
15: "VAA", signed int16, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
16: "VZA", signed int16, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
17: "NDVI", float ∈ [-1, 1], EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
18: "EVI", float, EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
19: "NDWI", float ∈ [-1, 1], EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
20: "MSAVI", float ∈ [-1, 1], EPSG:32620, 7551x7711 px
properties: 
Object (110 properties)
```

Following code loads each one of 4800 images of the Image Collection with only one band: 'MSAVI'. It has a palette with 4 colours for a good visualization.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-110.99184566101088, 33.80712333566572],
          [-110.99184566101088, 33.34947321463731],
          [-110.44252925476088, 33.34947321463731],
          [-110.44252925476088, 33.80712333566572]]], null, false);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["MSAVI"],
                     "min":-0.1185,
                     "max":0.5,
                     "palette":["fff80a","f78c04","ff2804","0f0aff"]};

function maskClouds(image) {
  
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    var cloudShadowBitMask = 1<<3;
    var cloudsBitMask = 1<<5;  
    
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
    
     // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
    
      // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
  
  var addNDVI = function (image){
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
  };

  var addEVI = function (image){
    var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - Red) / (NIR + 6 * Red - 7.5 * Blue + 1))',{    // C1=6, C2=7.5, L=1
    'NIR': image.select('B5'),
    'Red': image.select('B4'),
    'Blue': image.select('B2'),
    }).rename('EVI');
  evi = evi.toFloat();
  return image.addBands(evi);
  };
  var addNDWI = function (image){ 
    var ndwi = image.expression(
    'NDWI = (Green – NIR) / (Green + NIR)',{
      'Green': image.select('B3'),
      'NIR': image.select('B5')
    });
  ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B3']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndwi);
  };
  
 var addMSAVI = function (image){
   var msavi = image.expression(
   '(2 * nir + 1 - ( (2 * nir + 1)**2 - 8 * (nir -red) )**(1/2) ) / 2',{
     'nir': image.select('B5'),
     'red': image.select('B4')
   });
  msavi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('MSAVI');
  return image.addBands(msavi);
 };

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
  .filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-01-15')
  //.map(maskClouds)
  .map(addNDVI)
  .map(addEVI)
  .map(addNDWI)
  .map(addMSAVI);

print(l8);

var test = l8.select(['MSAVI']);

print(test);
Map.centerObject(geometry, 5);
Map.addLayer(test, imageVisParam, 'test');
```

In following picture it can be observed part of 4800 images loaded with 'MSAVI' band. It corroborates that your code has not any issue.

[image]